# overwriting CSS rules

Tags: html, css

This is probably pretty simple, but I can't seem to figure it out or find an answer.

I have an html element `<div class="box">`

This element has a set rule in its original style sheet :

```
.box {
width: 40%;
}
```

I'm using a Custom CSS sheet that overwrites the original stylesheet without touching it.

I need to change this rule to :

```
.box {
max-width: 40%;
}
```

So basically how do I add this new rule, but cancel the old one ??

Could it be something like ? :

```
.box {
width: 0;
max-width: 40%;
}
```

??

Comment: And an [interesting reading](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/).

Comment: A DIV's default width is 100%. The original CSS sets its width to 40%, and your CSS wants to limit the maximum width to 40%. By default, the div will always fill up as much width as it can. In your case, it will default to 40% width, unless you're explicitly setting the width to be less than that.

Answer (score 2):

You can reset to the automatic (default) width. A width with the value of `auto` tells the browser to calculate the width based on the other properties constraining the element.

```
.box {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To reset the width to what it would be by default, set the value to `auto`. So, your overwriting CSS rules would be:

```
width: auto;
max-width: 40%;
```

If you set the width to 0, then your box wouldn't even display. Max width is just what it sounds like - the widest the element can be, but it can also be any width less than that. So, setting a maximum width of 40px but a width of 0px will cause the element to have a width of 0px.

Comment: Great, that works, thanks so much .. one more quick question .. would I be able to set the value to `min-width: 40%` and `max-width: 40%` in the same time ? At the moment, the div doesn't go under 40% on a mobile, that's what I wanted, but now it stretches over 40% on a bigger device, because I removed the set `width: 40%`, so would I be able to limit the max stretch by adding the extra `max-width: 40%` ?

Comment: @JoeBloggs If you want different `max-width` values for different screen sizes, I'd check out [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). You could also use a `max-width` with a pixel value instead of percentage if that works for your use case.

Comment: @JoeBloggs I'm not sure I entirely understand your question. Are you saying that sometimes with max-width set to 40%, the div's width will exceed 40%?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the `CSS` rules work as the name says in cascade mode so you can do another .box in a different file and then link that file to the document, but remember in order to the rule to apply the new document must be the one to be linked to.

Also you can try in the same CSS document something like this:

```
.box {
 max-width: 40% /*Change this value to the one you want*/
}
```