# How to delete padding property?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

We are using a 3rd party payment gateway and its CSS is messing with our code. It has added the following attr to set all cols to padding 0.

```
[class*=col-] {
   padding: 0;
}
```

How should I remove this padding property? I don't want this padding property.

Comment: That looks like a very badly designed payment gateway with the capability of messing up other styles on your site :/ the problem with `padding` is that since it is not inheritable from parent, using `padding: unset` will not fix your issue :(

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173752/overwriting-css-rules?

Comment: You **never** *just* use the `*=` selector. In your case `*=col-` might also match elements like  `"racol-1"` `"tricol-green"` etc.

Answer (score 2):

## Reseting

```
[class*=col-] {
   padding: initial;
}
```

make sure that the styling file is linked after the third party file, like:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="third party">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style that have padding initial">
  <!--OR-->
  <style>
    [class*=col-] {
      padding: initial;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

> When multiple declarations have equal specificity, the last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element.
> --- [Specificity - Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#how_is_specificity_calculated)

### Note

if this didn't work, write `!important` after the styling like this

```
[class*=col-] {
  padding: initial !important;
}
```

## Removing

you can use JS to remove the property: `removeProperty()`,

## Re-Setting

or just set the padding everywhere you want and add `!important` in the end.
But,

> When an `important` rule is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declarations. Although technically `!important` has nothing to do with specificity, it interacts directly with it. Using `!important`, however, is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets. When two conflicting declarations with the `!important` rule are applied to the same element, the declaration with a greater specificity will be applied.

so don't use it only when you're editing external plugins/libraries like your case:

> Only use !important on page-specific CSS that overrides foreign CSS (from external libraries, like Bootstrap or normalize.css).

---

**Resources**
[Specificity - Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#how_is_specificity_calculated)

Comment: You never *just* use `*=` And your answer is **bug-prone and incorrect**. If something **starts-with** (like you presumed `*="col"`) than you use `^="col-"`, and as a fallback than you use `*=" col-"` (**with a space prefix**), All together: `[class^="col-"], [class*=" col-"] { /*styles here*/ }`

Comment: well, I just selected WHATEVER the selector in 3rd party selects, so if the selector of `padding: 0;` don't work, the selector of `padding: initial;` also don't work and this is what he needs

Comment: Just to mention - For OP specific case though might be *OK* - but - `!important` can only lead to worse problems and bad stylesheet coding habits; should be avoided at all costs. Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity .

Comment: first, I'm sorry about what happened in the previous deleted answer, thank you for trying to improve my question, and sorry for me bc I didn't appreciate it. Thank you for the tip in this answer, it will also help me improve my code!

Comment: you can check the edit, I didn't totally remove `!important` because it may be the only solution, in the link you provided "Only use !important on page-specific CSS that overrides foreign CSS (from external libraries, like Bootstrap or normalize.css)"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception

Answer (score 1):

You can't really remove a property. You can only write a selector to give it a different value.

Setting it to [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) should give the element back its default value.

It won't cause it to revert to an early style you've applied through. If you want that then you should make the original assignment override through the [specificty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the selector where you added it.

Answer (score 1):

## variables

You could do:

```css
.my-class[class] /* for specificity */ {
  padding: var(--padding);
}
```

and then for every tag with the `.my-class` class make a `--padding` of your choice

## or the obvious

```css
.my-element[class] {
  padding: [padding]
}
```

Comment: Like Quentin said, setting it to `initial` should give the element back its default value, but normally you would set it to something like `20px` because the default values sometimes differ between browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for the CSS `removeProperty()`?

> The CSSStyleDeclaration.removeProperty() method interface removes a property from a CSS style declaration object.

Check more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty)